# jQuery - Animation flicker using hover()

Tags: jquery, flicker, jquery-animate

I have a setup as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857998/stop-jquery-animations-stacking) which works perfectly.  Essentially a drop down menu grows when you move your mouse over it to expose more options.

There is, however, a small issue.  If you move the mouse outside of the `#dropdown` div and then back in again quickly it constantly fires the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events causing a never ending cycle of flickering.  How can I get around it?

Here is my current jQuery code

```
$("#dropdown").hover(function() { 
        $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo('fast',1);
        $("#options").stop(true,true).slideDown();
    }, function() { 
        $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo('fast',0.1);
        $("#options").stop(true,true).slideUp();
    }
);
```

And current HTML code

```
<div id="dropdown">
    <div id="optionsPeek">Options</div>
    <div id="options">
        <!-- Links here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

`dropdown` is visible by default (10% opacity), `optionspeek` is always visible and once you hover over it, the `options` div slides down and the links inside it become visible.

Comment: Can you post the html markup? I'm guessing `#options` is not inside `#dropdown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add a `delay()` to the fadeout? For example 1-2 seconds. That way you can move your mouse away and back onto the dropdown without causing any animations.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: This looked good but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with `stop()`

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to deal with such issues is to use the [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plug-in. It was designed to prevent the flicker problems you're having.

Answer (score 1):

use:

overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to be getting the flickering you mentioned, but then again - I did create the markup because yours wasn't available.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dropdown").hover(function() { 
        $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo('fast',1);
        $("#options").stop(true,true).slideDown();
    }, function() { 
        $(this).stop(true,true).fadeTo('fast',0.1);
        $("#options").stop(true,true).slideUp();
    }
);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dropdown" style="width: 300px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid black;">DROPDOWN</div>
<div id="options" style="width: 300px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid black;">OPTIONS</div>

</body>
</html>
```