# Immediately stop jQuery animate positioning animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following script to move elements in a canvas randomly:

```
function makeNewPosition(){
    
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}

function animateDiv(element){
    
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $(element).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, 5000, function(){
        animateDiv(element);        
    });
    
};
```

Now i need to immediately stop the animation when clicking a button. How is this possible?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: $(".buttonClassName").click(
      function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         console.log('button was clicked');  //add code here to stop animation     }
   );  Here's a hint how to stop the animation with .stop https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858013/3825777  Here's a stack snippet showing how buttons work https://stackoverflow.com/a/5470762/3825777